# How do you properly deploy SolidJS app to Netlify

Tags: solid-js

I have successfully deployed a SolidJS app to netlify just fine, but I ran into an issue where additional routes other than `/` cause the app to crash. Having previously deployed React apps to Netlify, adding a `_redirects` in the public folder works fine, but I'm not exactly sure where I should in my project directory the file should go since my local SolidJS  project has to `public` folder. I tried adding a `dist` folder under my `client` folder, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Is there any solution to this unique to SolidJS? Is a `_redirects` file the right way to go?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Netlify redirects routing docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/), there are two ways to implement this. Given you can't do it the first way, perhaps the second one would be your workaround:

> Add one or more redirects tables to your [Netlify configuration file](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#redirects).
> This method allows for more structured configuration and additional
> capabilities, as described in the Netlify configuration file syntax
> [section below](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-netlify-configuration-file).

Hope this helps.